# Prevent macOS automatically making a desktop when connecting to an external monitor

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, window-manager

Title says most of it. I am running 20 desktops in macOS Monterey and use both an external monitor frequently. Whenever I connect my macbook to the external monitor, a desktop is automatically created at the leftmost position of the secondary monitor. This shifts all my desktops across by one (positions of desktops are remembered and re-implemented when connecting an external monitor), breaking my window management keybinds. Deleting it when I connect the external monitor and putting it back before I disconnect it (or else the leftmost desktop is removed) is my current (and bad) solution.

Previously asked (and mostly unanswered) [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367838/remove-the-default-desktop-space-on-a-second-monitor). Viable workarounds also appreciated if solving this directly is a 'because Apple' issue.

(I'm also using amethyst, which may have a window assignment solution itself)

Comment: This has cropped up before, but with no defitine fix - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157540/yosemite-auto-creates-multiple-desktops-spaces-on-main-monitor

Comment: [Love the user name btw, made me laugh out loud... though not sure it's something i'd have thought anyone would want to be called after. I do hope you know it's a movie industry term & what one actually is ;))